# AJAX/JQuery: Submit form and call function without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm attempting to use ajax/jquery to submit a form comprised of dropdown menus, with the intention of displaying information from a MySQL database based on the form input. Without ajax/jquery, the page functions properly. However, I don't want the page to refresh once the form is submitted, so that the selected dropdown options remain showing. My ajax/jquery is not very good, and I know this is where I'm having trouble. my code is as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(funtion(){
var $form = $('form');
$form.submit(funtion(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(), 
        cache: false,
        success: displayResults
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

the function displayResults is the function that I want to call when the form is submitted, but as of right now, when i click submit, the form refreshes and no results are displayed. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to prevent the default form submit

Comment: Ok. But is my syntax, etc corrrect? When I click submit, the function displayResults doesn't get called.

Comment: It isn't correct. You need to add the property `url:$(this).attr('action')` for it to work as you want.

Comment: As a side note, you can use `var $this=$(this);` as the first line in your function. It will increase performance by reducing the number of times you call the jQuery library.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(funtion(){
var $form = $('form');
$form.submit(funtion(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(), 
        cache: false,
        success: displayResults
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

This prevents the form from submitting by preventing the event from firing. In vanilla javascript you could return false on submit and it would be the same.

Comment: Notice that sometimes the browser might not like that you use `e.preventDefault();`. In those cases, having `return false;` may help. Also, this is used to prevent propagation of the event in both fases (even though jQuery only handles the events on *bubbling*  fase.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to submit your form and prevent default behavior of form submit using `e.preventdefualt()` which will prevent event from firing,To serialize form data use `serializeArray()` ,use `success` and `error` to debug ajax call.

```
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
{
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            console.log(data); //display data Results 
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            console.log(errorThrown); // dispaly error
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});

$("#ajaxform").submit(); //Submit  the FORM
```

Answer (score 0):

The .submit() it will be the same as use the submit button. You have to use a button with the click event.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(funtion(){
    var data1 = $('#field1').val();
    // the same with all the values
   $('#button').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: ({dat1: data1} ),
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
         displayResults(); 
        }
      });
   });

});

</script>
```